# How to access a link embedded in a JSON dictionary using AlamoFire/ ObjectMapper?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

This is the objectmapper I'm using:

[ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper)  /  [AlamoFireObjctMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper)

Here is the JSON data I'm working with, I'm trying to access the "link" value:

```
channels =     (
  {
    social =             {
      facebook =                 {
        "facebook_id" = 47360808996;
        link = "https://www.facebook.com/CBS";
      };
      twitter =                 {
        link = "https://twitter.com/CBS";
        "twitter_id" = 97739866;
      }
    }
  }
)
```

I've created custom objects to represent each level of the JSON dictionary:

```
class SocialInfo: Mappable {

  var channels: Social?

  required init?(map: Map) {
  }

  func mapping(map: Map) {

    channels <- map["channels"]

  }
}

class Social: Mappable {

  var facebookSocial: Facebook?
  var twitterSocial: Twitter?


  required init?(map: Map) {
  }

  func mapping(map: Map) {

     facebookSocial <- map["facebook"]
     twitterSocial <- map["twitter"]

  }

}


class Facebook: Mappable {

  var facebookLink: NSURL?

  required init?(map: Map) {
  }

  func mapping(map: Map) {

    facebookLink <- (map["link"], URLTransform())

  }
}
```

Initialy I had the "facebookLink" under the "Facebook" class as a string but it kept returing nil.  I then tried the URLTransform to change it to a type of NSURL but now it's throwing the error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Here is how I'm trying to retrieve the JSON data:

```
 func getSocialInfo (completionHandler: @escaping (SocialInfo?, Error?) -> ()){

    Alamofire.request("\(baseURL)/\(apiKey)/show/950", method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).validate ()
      .responseObject{  (response: DataResponse<SocialInfo>) in

        switch response.result {
        case .success:
          let socialInfo = response.result.value

          print("This is the social info: \(socialInfo?.channels?.facebookSocial?.facebookLink)")


          completionHandler(socialInfo!, nil)

        case .failure(let error):

          print("Sorry there was an error: \(error)")
          completionHandler(nil,error)
          return
        }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the link as a string

```
var stringURL:String?
```

Getting the link

```
stringURL <- map["link"]
```

Convert the `stringURL` to `URL`

```
if let url = URL(string: stringURL) {
// do something 
}
```

Also, note that this will not work, as you are particularly saying that the `facebookDictionary` is = to your `Facebook` object.

```
 class Social: Mappable {

  var facebookSocial: Facebook?
  var twitterSocial: Twitter?

  fileprivate var facebookDictionary:[AnyHashable:Any]? 
  fileprivate var twitterDictionary:[AnyHashable:Any]?
  required init?(map: Map) {
  }

  func mapping(map: Map) {

     facebookDictionary <- map["facebook"]
     twitterDictionary <- map["twitter"]

     if let _facebookDictionary = facebookDictionary,
        let _twitterDictionary = wittertDictionary {

        let twitterMap = Map(mappingType: .fromJSON, JSON: _twitterDictionary)
        let facebookMap = Map(mappingType: .fromJSON, JSON: _facebookDictionary)

     /// Here you can initiate both object using map.

        facebookSocial = Facebook(map: facebookMap)
        twitterSocial = Twitter(map: twitterMap)

    /// If you want to use mapping function, set this as:

        facebookSocial = Facebook()
        twitterSocial.mapping(map: twitterMap)

        facebookSocial = Facebook()
        twitterSocial.mapping(map: twitterMap)
     }

  }

}
```

As you did not create a new map using the social dictionary, both objects will always be `nil`

Same for **Social**, first create a `map` out of Social `dictionary`.

Comment: Ok, I see how that would work but for some strange reason it keeps returning nil.

Comment: Which returns nil, the string or the URL?

Comment: When I print the ("This is the social info: \(socialInfo?.channels?.facebookSocial?.facebookLink)"), it returns nil

Comment: So the string returns nil

Comment: What about the rest of the JSON, do all return nil?

Comment: Do you get the facebook_id?

Comment: I don't get the facebook id. When trying to access anything in this particular dictionary it returns nil but other parts of the JSON it returns it fine.

Comment: @SwiftyJD See my updated answer ;). This is not tested, I wrote it here to check if compiles.